# Get server node failed [CANNOT_MEET_AREA_DEMAND] https://webrtc2-ap-web-2.agoraio.cn/api/v1

Tags: javascript, angular, webrtc, agora.io

I can make basic video call with temprory token from agora.io but when i create token from my server i get this error. I am using NgxAgora packet. I try to set areacode but there is no option for this in NgxAgora.
here is my angular code:

```
 this.api.getmethod("appointment/gettoken/" + atob(this.acRouter.snapshot.params.id)).subscribe((data) => {
    this.token = data['token']
    this.client = this.ngxAgoraService.createClient({ mode: 'rtc', codec: 'h264' });
    
   
    this.assignClientHandlers();
  
    this.localStream = this.ngxAgoraService.createStream({ streamID: this.uid, audio: true, video: true, screen: false });
    this.assignLocalStreamHandlers();
    // Join and publish methods added in this step
    this.initLocalStream(() => this.join(uid => this.publish(), error => console.error(error)));
  })
```

and i use this function in web api side using C#:

```
 public string createagoratoken(string appointmentUid,DateTime appointmentDate,int appointmentId)
    {
        var tokenbuilder = new AgoraEntegration.Media.AccessToken(AgoraEntegration.AgoraEnums.AppEnums.appId, AgoraEntegration.AgoraEnums.AppEnums.appCertificate, appointmentUid, appointmentId.ToString());

        appointmentDate = appointmentDate.AddMinutes(20);

                    
        Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(appointmentDate.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;

        tokenbuilder.addPrivilege(AgoraEntegration.Media.Privileges.kJoinChannel, (uint)unixTimestamp);
        tokenbuilder.addPrivilege(AgoraEntegration.Media.Privileges.kInvitePublishAudioStream, (uint)unixTimestamp);
        tokenbuilder.addPrivilege(AgoraEntegration.Media.Privileges.kInvitePublishVideoStream,(uint)unixTimestamp);
        string token = tokenbuilder.build();
        return token;

    }
```

Also i use this library for acces token
[Github access token for C#](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/blob/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/csharp/src/AgoraIO/Media/AccessToken.cs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CANNOT_MEET_AREA_DEMAND` usually comes when: The connection fails because the user is outside the chosen region for connection. For example, if you set `ClientConfig.areaCode` as `[AgoraRTC.AREAS.EUROPE]`, and a user tries to join the channel in North America, this error occurs. If ClientConfig.areaCode is not explicitly set, then by default the SDK requests servers across multiple regions and chooses an optimal connection, so the console log may print this error when a user joins the channel. In this case, you can ignore the error.

Try setting areaCode to GLOBAL:

```
this.rtc = AgoraRTC.createClient({
  //
  areaCode: ['GLOBAL']
});
```

Comment: When i write areCode i am getting this error:  Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error TS2345 (TS) Argument of type '{ mode: "rtc"; codec: "h264"; areaCode: string[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ClientConfig'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'areaCode' does not exist in type 'ClientConfig'.

Comment: Use `{ mode: "rtc"; codec: "h264"; areaCode: ['GLOBAL']; }`

Comment: I added "areaCode: string[]" to client-config.model.d.ts file after this areaCode:['GLOBAL'] works. Thank you.

Comment: That's great @hasim. Do mark my answer as the right answer and upvote it for others to refer in the future.